# Exporting the react-table to excel format

Tags: react-table

Looking for a way to add an "Export to excel" button to a react-table which is an npmjs package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table).

I need to add a custom button for exporting the table data to an excel sheet in the xls format. I also want to download only the filtered data in excel

I tried using react-export-table-to-excel package. But the data is getting downloaded as undefined.

Comment: react-export-table-to-excel works fine but the only problem is that the xls file is actually an html and excel shows warning when opening that file

Please show some code if you get undefined data so i can try to help you.

Comment: you can use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-table-to-excel
you can customize the export button as you like